# Is it worth caching glsl uniform location in code?

Tags: opengl, glsl

I would like to have ability to set uniforms via their actual names in the shader

```
myProgram.uniform3fv("uniformVector", 0.0f, 0.1f, 1.0f);
```

do I have to cache locations in some form of a map?

```
std::map<std::string, unsigned int> // or unordered_map
```

or maybe OpenGL (on desktop) caches this anyway, so I would not have any performance difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OpenGL specification defines functionality, not performance. So there's no way to know how any particular OpenGL implementation will store the list of active uniforms or how fast `glGetUniformLocation` will be, relative to `std::map` performance.

So really, it's up to you. If you want consistent, *known* performance, do it yourself. If you want to take a chance on the vagaries of the OpenGL implementation, then query it whenever you want. Personally, I'd say ditch names and go with locations. That way you get maximum performance.

Comment: so as in most cases, we cannot rely on assumptions (about the driver implementation) and it is better to do such simple caching on our own.